# link to download file from path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have path for a file on my machine which I would like to set download link for.  Here is what I'm trying:

In my model:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :data, :full_path
   has_attached_file :image,
      :path => :full_path
end
```

my controller looks like this:

```
def download
   @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
   send_file @exam.image.path, :x_sendfile => true 
end
```

And my view:

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_exam_path(@exam) %>
```

Now when I click download I get this error: `can't convert nil into String`
I know for a fact that `:full_path` contains the correct path to my file.  How can I fix this?

full error:

```
 TypeError in ExamsController#download

can't convert nil into String

Rails.root: /Users/Ryan45/Programming/rails_projects/oldV_rails_project
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/exams_controller.rb:83:in `download'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"392"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: Is `send_file @exam.image.path, :x_sendfile => true` line 83 of `exams_controller.rb`?

Comment: just ask, are you using `paperclip`?

Comment: I am using paperclip, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `@exam` is `nil` in your view. It might be because it isn't instantiated until inside the `download` action - but you're trying to use it in the `index` or `show` action, where it hasn't been built yet.

If that's the case, then you'll just need to add this (or something like it - I'm not sure if `params[:id]` will be available in the other action, as it is in the `download` action) to the action in your controller that's causing the error:

```
@exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
```

**Update**

Based on the update showing that the full error is pointing to line 83 of `exams_controller.rb`, which you confirmed in your comment as being:

```
send_file @exam.image.path, :x_sendfile => true
```

I would open up the Rails console (`rails c`), and enter:

```
@exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
```

Then I would start checking to see which part of `@exam` is `nil` by trying these two lines:

1. `@exam.image`
2. `@exam.image.path`

You might be able to figure out the problem based on that test.

Comment: Not sure if I follow.  You are correct in that I am trying to use it in my show action.  But according to my error report, the error comes from my download action, which already has that block of code.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I just misunderstood where the `can't convert nil into String` was originating. Can you add a copy of the full error you're getting in your question?

Comment: OK - I've updated my answer with the next steps I'd take to debug the issue.

Comment: The error changes now to `can't convert Paperclip::Attachment into String`

Comment: Ah ha! If I change `send_file @exam.image.path, :x_sendfile => true` to `send_file @exam.full_path, :x_sendfile => true` then the code works.  Guess I only needed the string for it to work.  Thank you for the help +1 and accept.